# Taking screenshot with Protractor that included Javascript alert

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

This is a legacy application that has JavaScript Alerts to notify the users that is under test.

I would like to take a screenshot of the screen when the Alert is present but as it turns out any controlFlow statement execution while the Alert is present throws

> UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Validation Errors}

My only option is to `browser.switchTo().alert().dismiss()` to dismiss the alert before screenshot can be taken.

Wondering if anyone has any solution.

> Chrome Driver: 2.23.409699
>
> Protractor: 3.3.0

Comment: Did you find any solution to the above issue. I am also trying the same but failing to take a screen shot of the alert box.

Comment: I did not find any workarounds so in a process of converting these Alerts to HTML modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a screenshot of a JavaScript alert with webdriver. You can, however, do it with the `Robot` class. Here is example code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("your url");

driver.manage().window().maximize();

// This step will result in an alert on screen
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("use xpath to enable alert")).click;

Alert alert = driver.switchTo.alert();

Thread.sleep(2000);

// Press the key combination of (Windows + PrintScreen) by using Robot Class
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);

alert.accept();
```